# How to turn NextJS typescript files into a intermediate machine readable format without building full project?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I have to provide the nextjs project to my client. But I want to make some changes to the typescript files so that it will not be understandble by human. Client will build and deploy to their production environment. How can I do that?

Bassially,

```
typescript files -> machine readable format (will send to the client with full project)
machine readable format -> build and deploy.
```

I can not build the project now because it needs to be built regularly to generate static files, those static files will be deployed in the production and I do not want to provide the code in human readable format.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `obfuscating` your code.

there are plenty of tools to achieve it.

you can search and try them to find out which works better for you.

here are some of the tools I have found that might be useful for you:

[nextjs-obfuscator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-obfuscator)

[jsCrambler](https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-protect-next-js-apps-with-jscrambler)